# incompatible types in assignment of ‘float’ to ‘float [16]’

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, floating-point

I have struct:

```
struct mat4 {
    float m[16];
    mat4();
    ...
    float *getFloat();
}

float *mat4::getFloat() {
    return m;
}
```

Now I want to make m equal to m from newly created matrix r:

```
void mat4::rotate(vec3 v) {
    mat4 r, rx, ry, rz;
    ...
    matrix calculations
    ...
    m = *r.getFloat();
}
```

But this gives me error "incompatible types in assignment of ‘float’ to ‘float [16]’"
I have searched Google and tried different ways but no success so far.
Please tell me how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r.getFloat()` is returning a pointer to a single float. This is dereferenced to give a single float, and then assigned to an array of 16 floats.

Assuming that `m` contains the entire state of `mat4`, you can use the built in assignment operator:

```
*this = r;
```

The compiler will automatically implement the struct dump/ memcpy to copy all 16 floats.

Answer (score 8):

`getFloat()` returns a pointer. `m` is an array. If you want to copy all of what is returned into `m` you will need to use `std::copy` or `std::memcpy`:

```
std::memcpy(m, r.getFloat(), sizeof(m));
```

If you meant to get just one float from `getFloat()` you could do:

- `m[0] = *r.getFloat();`

Comment: Definitely see the other answer about using C++ ways to solve this instead too though. Using something like `std::vector` or `tr1::array` is far better than worrying about handling it all yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::copy` as:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::copy(r.m, r.m+16, m);
```

Also, if you can use `r.m` directly, why call `r.getFloat()` then?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use naked C arrays. This is C++, we can do a lot better:

```
#include <tr1/array>  // or <array> if you're in MSVC or GCC

typedef std::tr1::array<float, 16> myfloats;

int main()
{
  myfloats a, b;
  a[0] = /* ... fill the array */
  b = a; // done
}
```

You can also put the array into your matrix structure:

```
struct mat4
{
  typedef std::tr1::array<float, 16> myfloats;

  myfloats & data() { return m_data; }

  mat4(); /* ... etc.  ... */

private:
   myfloats m_data;
};
```

You should be able to just assign variables of type `mat4` to each other directly!

Answer (score 0):

r.getFloat() returns a pointer to "its" `m`. Arrays cannot be copied with simple assignment; you would have to work either with `memcpy()` or `memmove()` or with a `for` loop over the array elements.